# pdev destroys c/c++ operations

Tags: eclipse, pydev

After a installation of the pdev ( manually cause via "install new software" didn't work ) the normal c/c++ operations have a strange behavior.

e.g.:

- c files are not recognised as c files anymore. // no syntax highlighting
- an external editor is opening by a double click on a c or c++ file
  .
  .
  .
  .

If I remove the files in feuture and plugins all works fine.

Has someone a solution?

Eclipse 3.6.0 Hellios

Answer (score 0):

First such report I've seen...

Have you tried just adding back the c/c++ file associations at window > preferences > general > editors > file associations?